# Cropping raster (rectangle) with shapefile (mask) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, extract-by-mask

[image: My study area is in black, and in grey the shape of Portugal]

**My study area is in black, and in grey the shape of Portugal**.

I am creating my study area. It corresponds to the coastal area of Portugal. I have a shapefile for Portugal. I want to crop a raster that corresponds to my study area ( a rectangle), with the shape of Portugal, but what I need is the ocean, so the part that is outside of the mask, the complementary part.

How can I do that?

Comment: Create a new mask which contains the ocean?

Comment: How can I create a mask with the ocean from the shape of Portugal?

Comment: I only need the black part you can see in the image. I need to subtract the Portugal polygon from the rectangle.

Comment: By using `difference` on a polygon covering the ocean.

Comment: Difference is a function on QGIS? Sorry Erik, I am really not an expert....

Comment: Google difference and QGIS?

Comment: Yes I found it thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) First, create a rectangle which encompasses your raster.

(1a) Start **Extract layer extent** tool (in `Layer tools` group).

[image]

(1b) Select your raster as the Input Layer. Run the tool.

[image]

(2) You will get a `Extent` layer.

(2a) Now start **Difference** tool (in `Vector overlay` group).

[image]

(2b) Select newly created `Extent` as the Inpur Layer. Also select your coastal polygon layer as the Overlay Layer. Then run the tool.

[image]

(3) You would see `Difference` layer (i.e. your ocean area).

(3a) Start **Clip raster by mask layer** tool (in GDAL > Raster extraction).

[image]

(3b) Select your raster as the Input Layer, and Difference polygon as the Mask Layer. Click on the checkbox for `Create an output alpha band`. Run the tool.

[image]

(4) Hope your final output is something like below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your explenation, it has been very useful and I solved my problem!